# Geometric Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, quadratics

The first term in a geometric series is 4 and the sum of the first three terms is 64. Find the sum of the first eight terms of the series.

I know the a value is 4, but I'm unsure of how to find the r value.

This is what i have tried:

$a+ ar+ ar^2 = 64$

$4r^2+4r-60=0$

This doesn't give an integer answer, so i doubt that it is the r value. Any hints as to where i went wrong?

Comment: I think you haven't gone wrong. Who says the answer has to be an integer?  If you're sure it must be an integer, check the original question and make sure the numbers are really 4 and 64, and not something else. But note that the question doesn't ask for $r$; it asks for the sum of the first 8 elements of the series, which may be better-behaved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a mistake: an $r$ that satisfies the above is $$r=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{61}-1\right)$$ (see http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4%2B4r%5E2%2B4r%3D64). You can check that this is indeed correct by
\begin{align*}
a & =4\\
ar & =4\cdot\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{61}-1\right)=2\sqrt{61}-2\\
ar^{2} & =4\cdot\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{61}-1\right)\right)^{2}=62-2\sqrt{61}\\
a+ar+ar^{2} & =4+2\sqrt{61}-2+62-2\sqrt{61}=64
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks. I have a quick question though. Isn't there two answers then because the quadratic formula generates two different answers.

Comment: There are two values of $r$ that satisfy the requirement.  The other is $r=\frac 12(-1-\sqrt{61})$

Comment: I should have stressed that more; I just said "an $r$" above.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \text{Let }f(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} ar^k = a\left(1-r^n\over{1-r}\right) $$ 
Question: $$ \text{Find } f(8)$$, $$ \text{ given    } a=4 \tag{1} $$ and $$ f(3)=64 \tag{2} $$

$$ \text{Solve for r using definition of } f(3) \tag{I} $$ 
$$ \text{Substitute for r in } f(8) \text { and simplify} \tag{II} $$

PART I:

\begin{align}
f(3) = 64 = & 4\left(1-r^3\over{1-r}\right) \\ \\
          = & 4\left(1+r+r^2\right) \\ \\
       16 = & r^2+r+1 \\ \\
        0 = & r^2+r-15 \\ \\
        r = & 1 \pm \sqrt{1+4(15)}\over{2} \\ \\
        r = & 1 \pm \sqrt{61}\over{2} \\
\end{align}

PART II

\begin{align}
f(8) = & 4\left(1-r^8\over{1-r}\right) \\ \\
= & 4 \left(1-r^4\right) \left(1+r^4\right) \over{1-r} \\ \\
= & 4 \left(1-r^2\right) \left(1+r^2\right) \left(1+r^4\right) \over{1-r} \\ \\
= & 4 \left(1+r\right) \left(1+r^2\right) \left(1+r^4\right) \\ \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
r = & 1 \pm \sqrt{61}\over{2} \\ \\
1+r = & 3 \pm \sqrt{61}\over{2} \\ \\ \\
r^2 = & 31 \pm \sqrt{61}\over{2} \\ \\
1+r^2 = & 33 \pm \sqrt{61}\over{2} \\ \\ \\
r^4 = & 511 \pm \sqrt{61}\over{2} \\ \\
1+r^4= & 513 \pm \sqrt{61} \over{2} \\
\end{align}

\begin{align}
f(8) = & 4 \left(1+r\right) \left(1+r^2\right) \left(1+r^4\right) \\ \\
= & \frac{4}{{2^3}} \left(3 \pm \sqrt{61}\right) \left(33 \pm \sqrt{61}\right) \left( 513 \pm \sqrt{61} \right) \\ \\ \\
f(8) = & \frac{1}{2} \left(99 \pm 36 \sqrt{61} \pm 61\right) \left(513 \pm \sqrt{61} \right) OR \\ \\
f(8) = & \frac{1}{2} \left(99 \pm 30 \sqrt{61} \pm 61\right) \left(513 \pm \sqrt{61} \right) \\ \\
\text {Thus for } X \in \{15,18\}, Y \in \{19,80\} \\
f(8) = & \frac{1}{2} \left(2Y \pm 2X \sqrt{61}\right) \left(513 \pm \sqrt{61} \right) \\ \\
= & \left(Y \pm X \sqrt{61}\right) \left(513 \pm \sqrt{61} \right) \\ \\
= & \left(513Y \pm 61\right) + \left(\pm Y \pm 513X \right) \sqrt{61} \\ \\
\end{align}

SOLUTION TABLES

\begin{array} {|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
Y & 513Y & 513Y + 61 & 513 Y - 61 \\ \hline
+19 & + 9747 & +9808 & +9686 \\
\hline
+80 & +41040 & +41101 & +40979 \\
\hline
\end{array}

\begin{array} {|c|c|}
\hline
\pm X & \pm 513X \\ \hline
\pm 15 & \pm 7695 \\ 
\hline
\pm 18 & \pm 9234 \\
\hline
\end{array}

SOLUTION WITH POSITIVE SIGNS SELECTED FOR ALL $ \pm $:
\begin{align}
f(8) = & \left(513Y + 61\right) + \left(Y + 513X \right) \sqrt{61} \\ \\
 = & \left(41040 + 61\right) + \left(80 + 9234\right) \sqrt{61} \\ \\
 = & 41101 + 9314 \sqrt{61} \\ \\ 
\end{align}

Comment: I noticed that the original question was to find the sum of the first 8 terms, while the answers focused on how to find values of r.   So I added this answer which covers both aspects.

Answer (score -1):

$$r^2+r-15=0\implies r=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{61}}{2}$$

$$\begin{align}1+r+r^2&=1+\left(\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{61}}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{61}}{2}\right)^2\\
&=1+\left(\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{61}}{2}\right)+\frac{31}{2}\mp\frac{\sqrt{61}}{2}\\
&=16\end{align}$$

Thus $a+ar+ar^2=a(1+r+r^2)=4\cdot16=64$